# OS not updating anything

Tags: updates

Elementary has stopped updating anything, giving the error message:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-all_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

Please can anyone suggest what I might do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal and run the following commands one at a time:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, regards.